# A-Frame VR Firefox to Google cardboard

Tags: firefox, aframe, virtual-reality

I wanted to view A-Frame based VR on my Cardboard when connected to PC. The A-Frame uses Firefox browser on PC. When I click on the VR mode it works fine on PC. It seems if one has htc-vive or oculus headsets and connects the same to PC they will be able to view VR and use the head tracking to move the 360 deg image. Is it possible to do something similar with A-Frame and Google cardboard?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. A-Frame works with Cardboard paired with a compatible smartphone. Cardboard holders are just a piece of hardboard and cannot interface with a PC.